# Using derived class in Template and storing it into vector of base class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, dictionary

I am trying to create a type-map in C++ using std::map and Type class which stores the type. Then there is one base class Base and some Derived classes which i want to store.

```
template <typename T>
class Type {

public:
    Type() {}

    virtual ~Type() {}
    virtual T* allocate() const { return new T; }
    virtual T* cast(void *object) const { return static_cast<T*>(object); }
};
```

This works just fine:

```
map<int, Base*> typeMap;
typeMap[1] = new Derive();
```

But when trying to do something like this, I got error: a value of type "Type< Derive> *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Type< Base> *"

```
map<int, Type<Base>*> typeMap;
typeMap[1] = new Type<Derive>();
```

Is there any chance to store something like this? I don't want any library solutions (non-opensource)

Comment: You are aware that you are mapping `int` to objects of type `Type<Base>*` instead of mapping `int` to an actual type.

Comment: Does the whole thing need to be a runtime-construct or is compile time OK?

Comment: Compile time is Ok @pmr

Comment: `Type<Base*>` and `Type<Derived*>` won't be convertible.

Comment: @Gelidus `I don't want any library solutions`  Well, you can get a library and see how they implemented what you are asking for.  There is no copyright on ideas, at least not theoretically.

Comment: I said, I don't want any closed-source solutions "(non-opensource)" @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Gelidus - Well, will `boost::any` suffice as the key type?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specialize a `struct` on an integer for each type you would like to map.

```
#include <cstddef> // size_t

struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

template<std::size_t i>
struct my_map;

// specialize the map (maybe shorten with a macro)
template<>
struct my_map<0> {
  using type = Base;
};

template<>
struct my_map<1> {
  using type = Derived;
};

// easier to use, if you compiler supports it:
template<std::size_t i>
using my_map_t = typename my_map<i>::type;


int main()
{
  my_map<0>::type* b1 = new Base();
  my_map<0>::type* b2 = new Derived();
  my_map<1>::type* d1 = new Derived();
  // my_map<1>::type* d2 = new Base(); error wrong type

  // prettier
  my_map_t<0>* b3 = new Base();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I use this to create new instance of object e.g. on map<0> with that type?

Comment: `my_map<0>::type()` will call the constructor of the type mapped to by 0. You can also first get a `typedef my_map<0>::type Name` and use `Name()`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @pmr's answer but using `std::tuple`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

class Base{};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<std::size_t i>
struct my_map
{
private:
    using myTuple = std::tuple<Base, Derived>;
public:
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, myTuple>::type;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<Base, my_map<0>::type>::value, "bad type");
static_assert(std::is_same<Derived, my_map<1>::type>::value, "bad type");
```

Comment: Nice, but you cannot extend a std::tuple at arbitrary places. Depending on your use-case this might be desired. I like your solution though.